# Querying all dictionaries in a python list

Tags: python

Without using loops to iterate through a list, is there a preferred syntax for retrieving a value of a given key from all dictionaries in a list?

This is a loop which achieves what I need:

```
>>> my_list = [{'foo':'bar'},{'foo':'buzz'}]
>>> [x['foo'] for x in my_list]
['bar', 'buzz']
```

This is intuitively how I think the same result should be achieved:

```
>>> my_list = [{'foo':'bar'},{'foo':'buzz'}]
>>> [my_list[*]['foo']]
['bar', 'buzz']
```

Comment: What's wrong with looping though the list? No, standard lists don't have that kind of magic syntax.

Comment: But... in the end you're looping the list. So what's wrong with having an explicit loop that clearly conveys that instead of some unclear syntax which will just confuse readers?

Comment: "This is intuitively how I think the same result should be achieved" then write up a PEP proposing this change, but there is no special syntax. For loops are very pythonic

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [`map`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/)

```
mylist = [{'foo':'bar'},{'foo':'buzz'}]

def extract(x):
    return x['foo']

a = list(map(extract, mylist))

print(a)
# ['bar', 'buzz']
```

Or as suggested by deceze in the comments: [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html?highlight=itemgetter#operator.itemgetter)

```
from operator import itemgetter

mylist = [{'foo':'bar'},{'foo':'buzz'}]
a = list(map(itemgetter('foo'), mylist))
print(a)
# ['bar', 'buzz']
```

Comment: `map(operator.itemgetter('foo'), ...)` would be more elegant…

Comment: @deceze Thanks. I never used it, but checked it out now and added that to the solution as well

Comment: Arguably the first method in the question is the most elegant...

Comment: I agree. List comprehension is the best

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any modules, or separate functions,

```
x = list(map(lambda x: x['foo'], my_list))

print(x)

>>> ['bar', 'buzz']
```